# Why SQL case statement between select and from?

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering why the SQL Server CASE Expression is always in between the Select and From statements, for example here:

```
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN score >= 94 THEN "A"
WHEN score >= 90 THEN "A-"
WHEN score >= 87 THEN "B+"
WHEN score >= 83 THEN "B"
WHEN score >= 80 THEN "B-"
WHEN score >= 77 THEN "C+"
WHEN score >= 73 THEN "C"
WHEN score >= 70 THEN "C-"
WHEN score >= 67 THEN "D+"
WHEN score >= 60 THEN "D"
ELSE "F"
END AS grade
FROM students_grades;
```

But not like this:

```
SELECT * FROM students_grades;
CASE
WHEN score >= 94 THEN "A"
WHEN score >= 90 THEN "A-"
WHEN score >= 87 THEN "B+"
WHEN score >= 83 THEN "B"
WHEN score >= 80 THEN "B-"
WHEN score >= 77 THEN "C+"
WHEN score >= 73 THEN "C"
WHEN score >= 70 THEN "C-"
WHEN score >= 67 THEN "D+"
WHEN score >= 60 THEN "D"
ELSE "F"
END AS grade;
```

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: The CASE expression is outside of the SELECT.    What are you expecting ?

Comment: The `CASE` statement forms an expression that is evaluated per row, depending on the value of `students_grades.score` and produces a value which results in a column `grade` in the results.

It would not make sense to have it after the `FROM` statement.

Comment: "grade" along with its formula is a column. You defne columns after the SELECT, before the FROM.

Comment: It isn't a "Case statement" - it is an expression not a statement

Comment: When we write 'GO' or ';' in the end of the statement. We tell to SQL engine that our desired query ended. In your sample query ended in the first line and after that, your case command isn't a valid t-sql command and you've got error for that. You could use Case statement in the Select and Where condition.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing as a `CASE` statement is actually a `CASE` expression. It is evaluated per row and depends on the value of `students_grades.score`.

It produces a value which is output in a column named `grade` in the results.

Expressions must be within a `SELECT` ( or `WHERE` ) statement.

It would not make sense to have an expression after the `FROM` statement because as an expression it must be within a statement.

To be clear, the `CASE` expression is not *between* the `SELECT` and `FROM` statements, it forms part of the `SELECT`, you could write this as `SELECT CASE ... END as grade, * FROM` and get the same data set returned but with a different column order.

Comment: I appreciate your response